# Assigning column name as cell value if column contains specific value

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R. I have a data frame with pairs of admission and discharge variables that should match e.g.:

```
  V1adm V1dis V2adm V2dis V3adm V3dis
1   120   120   yes   yes    60    60
2   110   110   yes  <NA>    40    40
3    60    NA    no  <NA>    NA    NA
4    90    NA  <NA>    no    20    NA
```

I have created a data frame with TRUE if either one of the variable pairs is missing:

```
# Variable names
adm_vars<- c("V1adm", "V2adm", "V3adm")
dis_vars<- c("V1dis", "V2dis", "V3dis")

# Create empty dataframe
pairs_NA<- matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=nrow(data))
pairs_NA<- as.data.frame(pairs_NA)
names(pairs_NA)<- paste(adm_vars, dis_vars, sep = '_')

# Add TRUE if adm OR dis variable NA
for(i in 1:3){
  x<- data[, adm_vars[i]]
  y<- data[, dis_vars[i]]
  pairs_NA[,i]<- is.na(x) | is.na(y)
}

  V1adm_V1dis V2adm_V2dis V3adm_V3dis
1       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
2       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE
3        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
4        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

For the rows where all 3 are missing, I would like to create a data frame that takes the column name from 'pairs_NA' as the cell value if that pair is missing (i.e. column is TRUE in pairs_NA). It should look something like this:

```
              1             2             3
3   V1adm_V1dis   V2adm_V2dis   V3adm_V3dis
4   V1adm_V1dis   V2adm_V2dis   V3adm_V3dis
```

Is there a way I can assign the column name of 'pairs_NA' as the cell value if there is a 'TRUE' in that column for each specific row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a logical index based on `rowSums` and replicate the column names of 'pairs_NA' after subsetting the rows where all the values are TRUE

```
i1 <- rowSums(pairs_NA) == ncol(pairs_NA)
matrix(names(pairs_NA)[col(pairs_NA[i1,])], ncol = ncol(pairs_NA))
#    [,1]          [,2]          [,3]         
#[1,] "V1adm_V1dis" "V2adm_V2dis" "V3adm_V3dis"
#[2,] "V1adm_V1dis" "V2adm_V2dis" "V3adm_V3dis"
```